# Why doesn't the C compiler give a redeclaration error inside a for loop body?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, declaration

In the C language, if we write this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    // for loop Body
}
```

The scope of variable `i` is inside the for loop body. It is OK.

But, if I write this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    long int i = 1; // Redeclaration of i
}
```

Here, the variable `i` is declared again inside the loop body, yet it successfully compiles and runs in C.

But, in C++, the compiler gives a **"redeclaration of 'long int i'"** error.

So, why doesn't the C compiler give a redeclaration error? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: There's no compiler bug

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

Comment: @user2864740 gcc prog.c -Wall -pedantic

Comment: You are not redeclaring `i` you are shadowing it in a nested scope.

Comment: @rsp -- Actually, what you need is `-Wshadow` in C, the warning is not issued through either `-Wall` or `-pedantic` (which you assume it would be, but isn't)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++ and C make a distinction here. According to [C11 (n1570) §6.8.5 ¶5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5), emphasis mine:

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
>   the scope of its enclosing block. **The loop body is also a block whose
>   scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement**.

Which translates to this for a for loop:

```
{
    declaration 
    while ( expression) {
        statement
        expression ;
    }
}
```

Anything you put in the `statement` part can hide whatever is introduced in the declaration. Now, C++(17, n4659) explicitly says something similar at [[stmt.for]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.for#1). But it also goes on to add:

> except that names declared in the init-statement are in the same
>   declarative region as those declared in the condition,

So here the second `i` is indeed an attempt at a re-declaration. The above may sound confusing (names declared in the condidion!?), but the "condition" here is defined like this ([[stmt.stmt]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#nt:condition)):

```
condition:
    expression
    attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq declarator brace-or-equal-initializer
```

It's that which allows while loops like this ([C++ only](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.while)):

```
while (T t = x) statement
```

And [you may not re-declare `t`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#3) inside the statement of the while loop.

---

Alternatively, the entire conclusion I reach is summarized in [[stmt.iter]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.iter#3) (thank you @T.C.):

> If a name introduced in an init-statement or for-range-declaration is
>   redeclared in the outermost block of the substatement, the program is
>   ill-formed.

Comment: The directly on point quote is [stmt.iter]/3.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no re-declaration inside the loop. Inside the loop body. `i` is defined every time the loop is entered, and the scope is only till the loop body.

Once the loop finishes the iteration, the variable does not exist anymore. (*First quote*)

That being said, what you are seeing is a result of *shadowing*. (*Second quote*)

Quoting `C11`,

> If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. [...]

and,

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not redeclaration.** *(Not literally, some may still call it though)*

See this carefully...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    int i = 5;
    printf("new i = %d\n", i);
}
```

Output of the above code:-

```
i = 0
new i = 5
i = 1
new i = 5
i = 2
new i = 5
i = 3
new i = 5
i = 4
new i = 5
i = 5
new i = 5
i = 6
new i = 5
```

Clearly, there are two different `i`'s

The newer `i` has a more local scope.

**Is it a bug?**

No

**What is the purpose?**

If it wasn't allowed, it might be very hard to maintain large projects, as you would constantly run into naming collisions.

Generally though, it is considered very poor practice to give the same name to different variables in different scopes, you should avoid doing that whenever possible.

**Why is there no warning message?**

Use `gcc file_name.c -Wshadow` to compile.

---

**EDIT:** ***You can also locally lock the originally declared variables by redeclaring them in for loops.***

Comment: "If it wasn't allowed, it would be very hard to maintain large projects, as you would constantly run into naming collisions." I'm not sure that follows. We do just fine in C++.

Comment: What Bathsheba said. And it's only disallowed in the outermost block anyway. Which makes sense. What possible naming collision could have that, such that you *immediately* need to hide the loop control variable?

Comment: It's just that C++ compiler is more strict. @Bathsheba